# How to loop for an amount of values got from a config.json file

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, for-loop, bots

How would i get a for loop to loop for amount of things in a config.json file in nodejs. Eg

what i want it to do:

```
const auth = require("./tokens.json")
//other code here

for tokens in auth {
        client.login(token)
}
```

My tokens.json would be like

```
"Tokens": ["xxxxxx",
"xyxyxx",
"asdasdaf",
"etc"]
```

Answer (score 2):

This will iterate the elements stored in the "Tokens" key:

```js
const auth = require("./tokens.json")
//other code here

auth["Tokens"].forEach((token) => client.login(token));
```